# RTNETLINK answers: No such device /Wireless card /kali linux

Tags: linux, wifi, internet, kali-linux

I've got an issue with alfa AWUS036NH. I cannot set it up. I get info : "No such device" or "Input/output error". I used command : "sudo ip link set wlan0 up" Kali version :5.5.0-kali1-amd64 release:2020.2 and yes I've made update before I'm stuck
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbClF.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPux3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Likely the name of wireless network interface is different. Check the output of the `ip link show` command to list of presented network interfaces in the system.

Comment: Apparently name is rather correct.  >> kali@kali:~$ ip link show
>>1... 2...
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:c0:ca:98:7f:28 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
 >>kali@kali:~$ sudo ip link set wlan0 up
>>RTNETLINK answers: Input/output error
**and still same problem